# Using breeze with ASP.NET bundling and minification

Tags: asp.net, breeze, bundling-and-minification

The [JavaScript Breeze Client NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Breeze.Client/) has an unusual JavaScript file pairing: there is a `breeze.min.js` and a `breeze.debug.js`. More typical is `foo.js` and `foo.min.js`, which is straightforward to use with ASP.NET bundling and minification: just include `foo.js` in the [bundle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.optimization.bundle.aspx), and by default, ASP.NET will use `foo.min.js` in production.

However, it's not clear what to do with `breeze.debug.js`. Should I include it in the bundle so I have access during development to any special debug code it contains? But then what about production? Will ASP.NET pick up the `.min.js` file, or will it minify the `.debug.js` file, in which case any debug code in the file would make it into production?

Comment: http://www.breezejs.com/ng-spa-template - This project has bundling and minification set up in ASP.NET project.  Check it out for guidance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include both `breeze.debug.js` and `breeze.min.js`. According to the description of the [Angular SPA template](http://www.breezejs.com/ng-spa-template#highlighter_998801), Web Optimization will remove one or the other. Which one it removes depends on the `debug` setting in `web.config`, which by default is determined by the build configuration.

Comment: PW Kad's comment on the question was the inspiration for this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can configure IgnoreList for bundling based on whether it is debug mode or not:

```
BundleTable.Bundles.IgnoreList.Ignore(".debug.js", OptimizationMode.WhenEnabled);
```